# Data in file not showing in web browser when returned in JSON

Tags: c#, json

I have a txt file which contains some data. I have some codes which will allow the web browser to display the data in the txt file. I want the data to be displayed in JSON format.

Here are my codes

**FileReaderClient.cs**

```
public class FileReaderClient : IHttpActionResult
{        
    public string filePath;       
    public FileReaderClient(string filePath)
    {
        this.filePath = filePath;           
    }
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(filePath))
            };

            return response;
        });
    }
}
```

**FileReaderController.cs**

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        var result = new FileReaderClient("C:\\Users\\attsuap1\\Desktop\\testfile.txt" );
        return result;
    }
```

When i do `return result;` i get the data in my txt file displayed in the web browser. However when i try to return it in JSON format, `return Json(result);`, i get the result as `{"filePath":"C:\\Users\\attsuap1\\Desktop\\testfile.txt"}` instead of the data in my txt file. Why is that so? And what should i do to display the data in the txt file in JSON format on web browser?

Someone please help me and thank you so much in advance.

Comment: can you please try way i suggested and let me know worked for you or not

Answer (score 2):

try as below to send file content back as response

```
[HttpGet]//http get as it return file 
        public HttpResponseMessage GetTextFile()
        {
            //below code locate physcial file on server 
            var localFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/timetable.txt");
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            if (!File.Exists(localFilePath))
            {
                //if file not found than return response as resource not present 
                response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Gone);
            }
            else
            {
                string data = string.Join(" ", File.ReadAllLines(localFilePath));
                response = new HttpResponseMessage
                {
                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                    Content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "text/html")
                };
            }
            return response;
        }
```

---

You are facing error because you are trying to access file with physical path ..you need to access file with `Server.MapPath` function .. as you are working with webpi or web application.

you have to do like this , create folder in your webAPI and put you file in that folder .

```
 string pathToFiles = Server.MapPath("~/files/testfile.txt");
```

for example check here : https://www.dotnetperls.com/mappath

Comment: I created the files folder however it is not appearing in the solution explorer is that ok? I refreshed a million times

Comment: @SushaNaidu - try to send detail as i given in code

Comment: All these codes goes under controller or FileReaderClient.cs ?

Comment: I mean should it go under controller or FileReaderClient.cs? When i put in these codes i get errors i am confused

Comment: @SushaNaidu - i should go here : public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Comment: And with my previous codes i was able to get the content but when i try to show it in JSON format, then i could not get the content. Does this codes allow the content to be displayed in JSON format?

Comment: `The name request does not exist in the current context` i get that error

Comment: @SushaNaidu - updated my answser , with working code , can you please try out , create method in your controller and call it  public HttpResponseMessage GetTextFile()

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me, however when i run the application, it shows a blank page. I included your codes in my controller and change the path to testfile.txt. Should i include anything in my FileReaderClient.cs?

Comment: @SushaNaidu - is that wokred for you

Comment: Did not :( When i run the application it showed a blank page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161690/discussion-between-pranay-rana-and-susha-naidu).